# creation of dataset using predefined set of values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to create a dataset with the following entries :

Flight_ID, Iternary_ID, Flight_Date, Booking_Date

I have the code here :

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from faker import Faker
import datetime
#import datetime
fake = Faker()
#import itertools
#from math import floor
random.seed(999)
## Create random iternary
no_of_days = 30
no_of_flights_per_day = 5
total_obs = no_of_days*no_of_flights_per_day
itr_a= np.random.randint(1,3,size = int(0.7*total_obs))
itr_b=np.random.randint(3,6,size=total_obs - len(itr_a))
itr = [1,2,3,4,5]*no_of_days
#itr = itr_a.tolist() + itr_b.tolist()
#for x in range(10):
#random.shuffle(itr)

## Generate flight ids
flight_ids = np.random.randint(10000,99999,size= total_obs).tolist() 
flight_ids = ["FT-" + str(x) for x in flight_ids ]

## Generating date for  flights
base = datetime.date(2019, 9, 1)
date_list = [base + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(30)]
date_list = date_list*5
#random.shuffle(date_list)
#####  Creating booking dataset
v = pd.DataFrame( list(zip(itr,flight_ids,date_list)),columns =['Flight_Id', 'Iternary_Code', 'date_list'])

flight_id_superlist = []
flight_final_date_superlist= []
flight_booking_date_superlist = []
flight_iternary_code_superlist=[]
for i in range(len(v['Flight_Id'])):
    no_days_booked = random.randint(4,30)
    flight_date = v['date_list'][i]
    booking_start_date = flight_date- datetime.timedelta(days=30)
    book_dates = [fake.date_between(start_date=booking_start_date, end_date=flight_date) for v in range(no_days_booked)]
    #book_dates.sort()

    flight_id_superlist = flight_id_superlist + ([v['Iternary_Code'][i]]*no_days_booked)
    flight_iternary_code_superlist = flight_iternary_code_superlist + ([v['Flight_Id'][i]]*no_days_booked)
    flight_final_date_superlist = flight_final_date_superlist + ([flight_date]*no_days_booked)
    flight_booking_date_superlist = flight_booking_date_superlist + book_dates

Flight_df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(flight_id_superlist,flight_iternary_code_superlist,
                                  flight_final_date_superlist,flight_booking_date_superlist
                                  )), 
               columns =['Flight_Id', 'Iternary_Code','Flight_Date','Booking_Date'
                         ])  
Flight_df.to_csv('./Flight_data.csv',index=False)
```

the expected output is to get get (Flight_ID, Iternary_ID, Flight_Date) entries for booking dates.

The problem that I am facing is that for a particular flight_Date and Itenary_ID multiple Flight_ID are getting assigned(screenshot attached).   dataframe v has the unique values for (Flight_ID, Iternary_ID, Flight_Date) stored and they should remain same although booking_date can change. I am not able to figure out the reason. Can anyone help with the same.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you made a simple mistake in the last `for` loop:

```
flight_id_superlist = flight_id_superlist + ([v['Iternary_Code'][i]]*no_days_booked)
flight_iternary_code_superlist = flight_iternary_code_superlist + ([v['Flight_Id'][i]]*no_days_booked)
```

As you can see you put the iternary codes in the flight ids superlist, and you put the flight ids in the iternary codes superlist :). Inverting them might help:

```
flight_id_superlist = flight_id_superlist + ([v['Flight_Id'][i]]*no_days_booked)
flight_iternary_code_superlist = flight_iternary_code_superlist + ([v['Iternary_Code'][i]]*no_days_booked)
```

Then for the rest, it is a bit too undocumented for me to understand if the logic is the one you had in mind.

Comment: Thank you for the observation, However it still doesn't solve the result. The basic idea is to generate some of the entries w.r.t booking dates with 150 pair values of (Flight_ID, Iternary_ID, Flight_Date). I am trying to generate the booking_date based on delta and number of bookings is randomized using the variable no_days_booked. and then creating the superlist with all data aggregated. is it possible for you to take a look at the code now?

Comment: I looked at the code and the output looks correct to me: each iternary id / flight date now always have the same flight id. So that seems to have solved your original question. If not, please provide *much* more precise explanation - I tried hard but frankly your explanation is not understandable at all :( ...

Comment: with the dataset, only ID 1 is generated for 01/09/2019 but there are 4 other ID's associated with it. So if 29 entries are generated, all entries are associated to 1, however it should have other ID's and iternary_code as well. I want to achieve that.

Comment: I understand that I would have to change the logic for `flight_id_superlist = flight_id_superlist + ([v['Flight_Id'][i]]*no_days_booked)` since it will only multiply the ID coming in and would provide me the same ID all the time but I want to randomly allocate the other ID's as well

Comment: I hope this is enough to understand the problem that I am facing with the current dataset